# Intranet Application - Data Access in separate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC intranet application which uses EF 6. I have setup the DataAccess project in a separate class library which has EF 6 referenced. I have an entity which implements an interface:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Collection : IAuditable
{
    // Properties
}
```

However, in the `SaveChanges` method I obviously don't have access to `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` as it is in a separate class library, so I was wondering how one would set this in `SaveChanges`?

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var addedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added);

    foreach (var dbEntityEntry in addedEntries)
    {
        var entity = dbEntityEntry.Entity as IAuditable;

        if (entity != null)
        {
            entity.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            // how do I set entity.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name?
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

### Edit

Following on from @CodeCaster solution, I have the following:

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly BTNIntranetRepository _repository; 

    public BreezeController(BTNIntranetRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _repository.LoggedInUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    // Methods
}
```

But `HttpContext.Current.User` is null

Comment: The fact your `HttpContext.Current.User`  is null is an entirely different issue, that might arise from how you set up your authentication and IoC container. What's it set to in an action method? A hack would be to set it each time on a repository before using it, but in that case you might as wel do `entity.CreatedBy=...`.

Comment: I've enabled Windows Auth and I can see the value of `Identity.Name` if I don't set it in the constructor (for example in one of the methods on the ApiController) but if I do, then `User` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in many ways.

You're not really showing relevant code, but you can for example give the library class you expose a public `string LoggedInUser` (or `ActingUser` or give it a name) property which you set when instantiating it:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private IDataSource _dataSource;

    public SomeController(IDataSource dataSource)
    {
        _dataSource = dataSource;
        _dataSource.LoggedInUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
    }
}
```

You can then simply use that property in your `IDataSource.SaveChanges()` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    // ...

    entity.CreatedBy = this.LoggedInUser;
}
```

Comment: The controller is an ApiController. The problem with setting it in the constructor is that the HttpContext.Current.User isn't set when I instantiate the controller in my IoC

Comment: I've edited my question to hopefully show more relevant code?

Comment: What I've done, is prior to calling SaveChanges on my repo, I call a method to set the current user on my repo, this in turn sets the value of `LoggedInUser` in the context and solved the problem! Thanks!